# Out of memory when sampling images using TF2.0 autoregressive model on Google Colab

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

The sampling function looks like this:

```
def sample_image(batch_size, model):
    image = np.random.choice(4, size=(batch_size, 28, 28, 3))
    for i in range(28):
        for j in range(28):
            for k in range(3):
                _ ,prob_output =  model(tf.Variable(image, dtype=tf.float32, trainable=False))
                prob_output = prob_output.numpy().reshape((batch_size,28,28,3,-1))
                # prob_output = tf.nn.softmax(prob_output, axis=-1)
                # print(prob_output.shape)
                for b in range(batch_size):
                    if k == 0 and b ==0: 
                        print(f'i:{i}, j:{j}, k:{k}')
                    # print(prob_output[b,i,j,k])
                    # prob = tf.nn.softmax(prob_output[b,i,j,k], axis=-1).numpy()
                    # print(prob)
                    # prob /= prob.sum()
                    image[b, i, j, k] = np.random.choice(4, p=prob_output[b,i,j,k])
                del prob_output
                del _

    return image
```

And when I ran this code to sample images on Google Colab, the RAM finally became OOM and the kernel shut down after that. How to avoid OOM while running on Colab?

Comment: try smaller batch size.

Comment: batch size has already been 1, still OOM  ; (

Comment: do you have 3 inner for loop and new a model in them so you have 28*28*3 model into your memory??

Comment: I initialized the model outside the function, followed by function call `sample_image(1, model)`

Comment: I think there is problem there. When you got memory error means you load many things to memory. try to comment your for loops and load the model just one time and for one image.